# A group action up to a function.

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, representation-theory, projective-space, simplex

Let $G$ be a group and an "action" $\psi$ of $G$ on a set $\Delta$ inside a vector space $M$, of the form:
$$\psi(g)\psi(h)v=(\psi(gh)+\phi(g,h))v$$
for $g,h\in G$, $v\in \Delta$ and $\phi$ a function on $G\times G$. There is a name for this kind of group action up to a function? clearly is not a group action, traditionally speaking, however it came up when studying actions on subsets from a well-defined group action. So, if $\Delta\subset M$ and $G$ acts on $M$, the projection to an arbitrary subset has been studied?

Comment: What does $+$ mean here?

Comment: I just made a little edit. Right, I'm assuming $G$ is acting on a vector space and I want to understand how it behaves the action when projected into a set (specifically convex subset). I'm thinking, for instance, in the action on the projective complex space $P_n(\mathbb{C})$ and how it projects in the simplex $\Delta_n$.

Comment: If you define $\phi(g, h) = \psi(g) \psi(h) - \psi(gh)$ then $\psi$ can be totally arbitrary and uniquely determines $\phi$. You'll need to specify some conditions on $\phi$ to get anything interesting here.